How do I get text from a block in a dwg file using the libredwg library?
I managed to get the plain text, but I do not know how to get it from the blocks. I also tried to find other libraries, but they don't compile for Visual Studio 2022.
Here is my code that reads the text:
int DWGTextLoader::loadFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    text.clear();
    this->filename = utf8_decode(filename);

    Dwg_Data dwg;

    memset(&dwg, 0, sizeof(Dwg_Data));
    int success = dwg_read_file(filename.c_str(), &dwg);
    if (!(success < DWG_ERR_CRITICAL)) {
        printer->printError(L"Wrong file!");
        return success;
    }

    char* text_value{ nullptr };
    int found{ 0 };
    int isnew{ 0 };
    std::wstring text2;
    for (BITCODE_BL i = 0; i < dwg.num_objects; i++)
    {
        if (dwg.object[i].type == DWG_TYPE_TEXT)
        {
            Dwg_Entity_TEXT* _obj = dwg.object[i].tio.entity->tio.TEXT;
            found++;
            dwg_dynapi_entity_utf8text(_obj, "TEXT", "text_value", &text_value, &isnew, NULL);
            text.append(separator + utf8_decode(text_value));
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        printer->printError(L"Text not found!");
        return 0;
    }

    dwg_free(&dwg);
    return success;
}

std::wstring utf8_decode(const std::string& text)
{
    if (text[0] == 0)
        return std::wstring();

    int size_needed = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, text.c_str(),
        static_cast<int>(text.size()), NULL, 0);

    assert(size_needed > 0);
    const size_t cnt = static_cast<size_t>(size_needed);
    std::wstring wstrTo(cnt, 0);

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, text.c_str(),
        static_cast<int>(text.size()), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);

    return wstrTo;
}

